# Find An Eigenvalue & Eigenvector from a given Eigenvalue and eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I was given a 3x3 matrix and I was given a complex Eigenvalue of -2+6i. They also gave me the eigenvector
[-6-2i]
[1]
[9i].
I have to find another eigenvector and eigenvalue that isn't given.

I attempted to use the formula Ax=lamdax. I was trying to solve for A with x being the eigenvector and lamda being -2+6i. That doesn't give me a matrix though. I'm lost.

Comment: Hint: If the matrix has only real values, then another eigenvalue will be $\lambda = -2 - 6i$ (the complex conjugate).

Comment: Oh. I feel dumb, thank you. Simple and easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Hyperion said, the new eigenvalue is -2-6i, so the eigenvector is -6+2i,1,-9i

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1172697)

Comment: @clathratus If I am not mistaken, this is a complete answer.

Comment: Then accept your answer.

Comment: @clathratus You can’t accept your own answer to a question until 48 hours have elapsed. You’d do well to familiarize yourself with these and other restrictions.